# Are fuzz tests replacible with randomized unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, fuzzing

I'm required to add some fuzz tests to my code, but looking at makes me think that I do not need dedicated fuzzer.

If we look at trivial approach, just testing through input, fuzzing will effectively test my arg parser.

If I create slices, e.g. dedicated small main, I'll have to create fake environment for the object, e.g. fake tcp interface so I can simulate something weird coming from the network, which looks quite like mocking.

So why use dedicated fuzzer, when I have perfectly good parametrized unit tests, and the only thing I need is to instantiate those once again, but this time with some random generator instead of data I've used for positive testing? Then I compile that instantiation into separate binary, and I have fuzz tests?

Am I missing something?